# To Find Colors Different in Two Images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-processing

I want to find the color group of blue removed from Image 2 compared to Image 1. 
[Image 1](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/06/consider-multibandread-for-reading-your-data/) and [Image 2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/74251/18754)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The fact that the images are jpegs makes automated systems quite hard to do

Comment: It is not a possible duplicate. It is the exact same user asking the same! XoD Masi, pease do not do that. Edit your question!.

Comment: @joojaa Good point! I must think some other example. I use eps normally.  Is png ok? Any better?

Comment: @Masi is it a vector image? PNG is better but if your original is vector then theres not much ooint in rasterizing it. But if its raster then png is better yes.

Comment: @joojaa I have vector images. I am practicing here with rosterized images. Feel free to answer how the handling differs between the two. Is doing such things easier in vector?  Can you use ImageMagick with Vectors?

Comment: Most probably this is much easier to do in vector originals than in the raster images. For one you much less likely th ave intermediate hues due to antialiasation. No you cant do that in imagemagik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just did it manually ... another way to detect the colors is to make any shape - brush . etc

and color this thing with the eyedropper ( normal eyedropper ) and the difference will be that you can zoom in as much as you want to detect any colors you want ..

like this example i made a various blue brushes and chose them with the mask then inverted the mask ...[image]

Comment: Yes,  this is a good direct way. I am also interested in indirect way.